# What does the regular expression ^(\d{1,2})$ mean?

Tags: regex

I am trying to understand what the regular expression ^(\d{1,2})$ stands for in google sheets.  A quick look around the regex sites and in tools left me confused.  Can anybody please help?

Comment: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yS5fU8/2) offers a clear explanation.

Answer (score 27):

- `^` Asserts position at start of the string
- `(` Denotes the start of a capturing group
- `\d` Numerical digit, 0, 1, 2, ... 9. Etc.
- `{1,2}` one to two times.
- `)` You guessed it - Closes the group.
- `$` Assert position at end of the string

Regular expression visualization:

[image: vis]

Comment: Rad. How'd you generate that?

Comment: @AlexDresko [Debuggex regex tool.](https://www.debuggex.com/) Handy! (See button: Embed on StackOverflow) As for the explanation... I wrote it myself.

Answer (score 4):

- `^` - start of a line.
- `(\d{1,2})` - captures upto  two digits(ie; one or two digits).
- `$` - End of the line.

Answer (score 2):

It means at least one at most two digits `\d{1,2}`, no other characters at the beginning `^` or the end `$`. Parenthesis essentially picks the string in it i.e. what ever the digits are

Comment: Parenthesis actually denotes a capturing group, not that they are part of the syntax itself. So `/^\d{1,2}$/` eq. `/^(\d{1,2})$/`

Answer (score 2):

- ^ matches the start of the line
- The parens can be ignored for now..
- \d{1, 2} means one or two digits
- $ is the end of the line.

The parens, if you need them, can be used to retrieve the digit(s) that were found in the regex.

Comment: `The parens can be ignored for now..` this one is totally wrong. In regex `()` called capturing groups. Any characters within the parenthesis are captured for later back-referencing.

Comment: The "for now" part of my answer indicates that I was trying not to make that an important part of the explanation _yet_. The OP didn't say anything about needing to use the group so I didn't want to emphasise that detail _yet_. But the last thing I did in my answer was to explain, roughly, what the parens (grouping) are for.